# Why I get the following error: "no match for 'operator=='" ? (nested class with template)

Tags: c++, class, c++11, templates, operator-overloading

Given the following code:

```
template<class T>
class TemplateClass {
    T val;
public:
    TemplateClass(T val) :
            val(val) {
    }
    TemplateClass(const TemplateClass& tc) = default;
    TemplateClass& operator=(const TemplateClass& tc) = default;

    class Ele {
        T x;
    public:
        Ele(T x) :
                x(x) {
        }
        template<class S>
        friend bool operator==(const typename TemplateClass<S>::Ele& e1,
                const typename TemplateClass<S>::Ele& e2);
    };
};

template<class T>
bool operator==(const typename TemplateClass<T>::Ele& e1,
        const typename TemplateClass<T>::Ele& e2) {
    return e1.x == e2.x;
}

int main() {
    TemplateClass<int>::Ele e1(4);
    TemplateClass<int>::Ele e2(3);
    if (e1 == e2) {  // *********** error
        std::cout << "ok" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

> no match for '`operator==`' (operand types are '`TemplateClass<int>::Ele`' and '`TemplateClass<int>::Ele`')

Can someone tell me how can I fix it and what is the problem?

Comment: It's seen so strange because that in fact I send to `operator=` two arguments from type 'TemplateClass::Ele'  , so what is the problem..?

Answer (score 2):

Nested name of a type belongs to [non-deduced contexts](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Non-deduced_contexts):

> 1) The nested-name-specifier (everything to the left of the scope resolution operator ::) of a type that was specified using a qualified-id:

So `operator==` fails to be invoked because template argument deduction fails; template parameter can't be deduced.

You might make it a non-template function, and define it inside the class definition. e.g.

```
template<class T>
class TemplateClass {
    ...
    class Ele {
        ...
        friend bool operator==(const typename TemplateClass<T>::Ele& e1,
                               const typename TemplateClass<T>::Ele& e2) {
            return e1.x == e2.x;
        }
    };
};
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/FENDJTacoP8XbAj8)

Or make it non-template member function, then you might define them out of the class definition. e.g.

```
template<class T>
class TemplateClass {
    ...
    class Ele {
        ...
        bool operator==(const typename TemplateClass<T>::Ele& e2) const;
        bool operator!=(const typename TemplateClass<T>::Ele& e2) const;
    };
};

template<class T>
bool TemplateClass<T>::Ele::operator==(const typename TemplateClass<T>::Ele& e2) const {
    return x == e2.x;
}
template<class T>
bool TemplateClass<T>::Ele::operator!=(const typename TemplateClass<T>::Ele& e2) const {
    return ! (*this == e2);
}
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/54XG396Hlsbm37qt)

Comment: And if I want know to implement `operator!=` and define it outside the class, how can I do it?

Comment: @MathQues I think you have to define it inside the class, same as `operator==`.

Comment: Can you add it to your answer? (I thought to implement `operator!=` by `operator==` and hence to define it outside the class...)

Comment: @MathQues Answer revised. You can make them member functions then define them outside of class definition. It's same for both `operator==` and `operator!=`.

Comment: But what if I will want to support at convert with this type? Because that these are symetric-operators we will need to define one from them as a friend and to implement the other outside the class , No?

Comment: @MathQues Then they have to be non-member functions, then you have to go with the 1st solution.

Comment: But even if I will go with the 1st solution, it's not clear how can I define `operator!=` outside the class (no as friend , but, implemented by `operator==`)...

Comment: @MathQues You can't. I mean if you define it as template function (you have to if you want to define it outside), it can't be invoked because of non-deduced context.

Comment: @MathQues You will have to define it inside the class, making the `friend` declaration a definition. No other solution, sorry. (But even if `operator==` is complicated, `operator!=` is rarely more than `return !(e1 == e2);`)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answers here, you can use [friend injection technique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barton%E2%80%93Nackman_trick) to fix the error:

```
template<class T>
class TemplateClass {
    // ...
    class Ele {
        // ...
        friend bool operator==(const Ele& e1, const Ele& e2) {
            return e1.x == e2.x;
        }
    };
};
```

Note that you do not need problematic `typename TemplateClass<S>::Ele` here at all.

Comment: And if I want to implement `operator!=` by `operator==` , can I do it without define the `operator!=` as friend?

Comment: @MathQues No, you have to declare and define `operator!=` the same way, or use [`boost::operators::equality_comparable`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/utility/operators.htm#equality_comparable1) to do it for you.